# document.forms[0].item is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I run the java script for a popup calendar on chrome I get this message. However it works on IE. I cannot figure out what this error means.

```
    function getDate(Src, Msg) {
                var left, top, date;
                date = document.forms[0].item(Src,0).value;
                date = window.showModalDialog('/QHOS/CalendarPopup.aspx?Src=' + Src + '&d=' + date + '&msg=' + Msg,'Calendar','dialogHeight:320px; dialogWidth:228px; edge:Sunken; center:Yes; help:No; resizable:no; status:No; unadorned:No; scroll:No;');
                if ( date != null ) { document.forms[0].item(Src,0).value = date; }
            }
```

It has to do with this line in particular.

```
date = document.forms[0].item(Src,0).value;
```

Comment: `date = document.forms[0].item(Src,0).value;` but you are trying to invoke a function - `item()` where is it declared?

Comment: Convention dictates that only constructor functions are stored in variables with names starting with capital letters. This makes `Src` and `Msg` poor choices of variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item). The `item` method is not well supported outside of Microsoft browsers.

Directly access the property from the node list instead.

```
forms[0][Src]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I was unaware of that. It works.